error in acessing pgadmin inteface even after proper download and adding path to environment variables
what may be the reason for the pg-admin not opening until its service is stoped in services and once the pgadmin interface opens the service needs to be started again to get the data need by the pgadmin. what error is this?
I tried several methods by re-installing the pgadmin and added the path to the environment  variable too and have verified the port number(5432) even then the above problem remains the same .
